# Atomic load in C with MSVC

Tags: c, visual-c++, atomic, interlocked

TL;DR: I need the Microsoft C (not C++) equivalent of C11's `atomic_load`.  Anyone know what the right function is?

I have some pretty standard code which uses atomics.  Something like

```
do {
  bar = atomic_load(&foo);
  baz = some_stuff(bar);
} while (!atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&foo, &bar, baz));
```

I'm trying to figure out how to handle it with MSVC.  The CAS is easy enough (`InterlockedCompareExchange`), but `atomic_load` is proving more troublesome.

Maybe I'm missing something, but the [Synchronization Functions list on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686360(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't seem to have anything for a simple load.  The only thing I can think of would be something like `InterlockedOr(object, 0)`, which would generate a store for every load (not to mention a fence)…

As long as the variable is volatile I think it would be safe to just read the value, but if I do that Visual Studio's [code analysis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173498.aspx) feature emits a bunch of [C28112](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh690609.aspx) warnings ("A variable (foo) which is accessed via an Interlocked function must always be accessed via an Interlocked function.").

If a simple read is really the right way to go I think I could silence those with something like

```
#define atomic_load(object) \
  __pragma(warning(push)) \
  __pragma(warning(disable:28112)) \
  (*(object)) \
  __pragma(warning(pop))
```

But the analyzer's insistence that I should *always* be using the `Interlocked*` functions leads me to believe there must be a better way.  If that's the case, what is it?

Comment: No choice, have to support MSVC :(.  It's fine if I should just do `#define atomic_load(object) (*(object))` (which is what I've done for MSVC in the past), but the code analyzer thing is giving me pause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think ignoring the analyzer is acceptable here, given [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684122(v=vs.85).aspx) says simple reads of register width variables are safe (32 bit on 32 bit systems, 64 bit on 64 bit systems). [The warning documentation itself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh690609.aspx) basically says it's being overly cautious, even when the access might be safe.

That said, if you want to shut it up, you can always use an idempotent `Interlocked` operation to get the desired behavior. For example, you could just define:

```
#define atomic_load(object) InterlockedOr((object), 0)
```

Since bitwise or with `0` is never going to change the value, and it always returned the original value, the end result is to read the original value while atomically writing nothing.

If you were simulating `atomic_load_explicit` with `memory_order_relaxed` you might get better performance by using [`InterlockedOrNoFence` to avoid memory barriers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh972672(v=vs.85).aspx), but for simulating the default (sequentially consistent) `atomic_load` you'd want to stick with `InterlockedOr`.

`InterlockedOr` was chosen mostly arbitrarily (on the theory that it might be slightly faster in hardware than an operation with carry like addition or subtraction), but `InterlockedXor` with 0 would should behave the same way, as would several other operations, as long as they were done with their identity value.

You could also use [`InterlockedCompareExchange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683560(v=vs.85).aspx) in a similar manner; testing would be needed to determine which was faster:

```
#define atomic_load(object) InterlockedCompareExchange((object), 0, 0)
```

where again, if the value is already 0, you set it to zero, but all you're really using it for is to get the return value, the original value before the no-op exchange.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I'm hesitant about `InterlockedOr`, which could lead to a spurious write, though maybe the compiler is smart enough to optimize it away.  `InterlockedCompareExchange` is a cool idea, hadn't considered that.  Since it really is safe, I think the best solution is the last snippet from my question (with the pragmas to disable the warning).  Since I'm doing the CAS in a loop a spurious failure from the load (like a torn read from a 64-bit value on a 32-bit machine) aren't the end of the world.

Comment: @nemequ: I swear I read the question twice, and completely missed the paragraph that mentioned `InterlockedOr`. Sorry about that. Glad I added the other option then. :-)

Comment: `_InterlockedCompareExchange` (on x86/x64 at least) almost certainly generates a `lock cmpxchg` instruction, which will write to the object regardless of whether the comparison succeeds ([cmpxchg](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpxchg#description)). This makes it incorrect to use `_InterlockedCompareExchange` for a function which should be able to accept read-only objects.